# Java Hibernate constraint for enum type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Inside my enitity I defined a field:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private TaskStatus status;
```

This field has enum type:

```
public enum TaskStatus {
    NEW, IN_PROGRESS, DONE
}
```

Inside my table this column has `character varying(255)`type. Is it possible to automatically limit this length using Hibernate or do I have to manually set `@Size` for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add annotation `@Column(length = 11)` to `status` properties (with length of your max enum).

Comment: Correct, but here's a point to note here. The possibility of the introduction of longer than 11 chars, constant in the enum would create problems (failure to insert new object) so one must consider a bigger length for future changes.